# Created a dual boot but only boots to Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, windows-8

A friend of mine had installed Ubuntu 16.04 using the "Alongside Windows 8" option and now the system only boots to Ubuntu.

How can we fix this?

Comment: Do you get a GRUB boot menu when you start your computer? If not, repeatedly hit the SHIFT or ESC key before Ubuntu starts to load, that should get you in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get GRUB bootloader but it doesn't show windows 8 try to update grub. Command in terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If you don't get a GRUB bootloader please read/follow these steps: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: I do get the grub bootloader and no it doesn't show win8.
run the command in the terminal not the grub command line right?

Comment: Run that command in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try using boot-repair, it's a tool that'll scan for existing OS on your file system and rebuild grub index. The "default" fix usually works for your kind of problem.

To install it, open a new terminal and type the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And finally

```
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

You can then launch it with `sudo boot-repair` and follow the instructions.

OR, do this all at once with this concatenated command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The answer above had already satisfied my needs. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need check if the Ubuntu included the other system in a grub config file. Don't forget that a second system need to be instaled in a "logic" partition inside a "secondary" partition.